# Event Click Kml Placemark

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

I created a placemark in kml with a name and ID = 'campania'

I uploaded it using the method `google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function())`

and I see a placemark on the map
I would like to add placemarks can be clicked, I found this method to get the ID of the placemark
`placemark=ge.getElementByUrl('http://web.uniparthenope.it/~0124000489/tw-2013/place.kml#campania');`

To make it clickable using the method

`google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'click',playTour);`

It does not work makes me appear a speech bubble with the name of the placemark when it should start the tour
and gives me this error

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getEventHandlersId' of null`

Can you help? Perhaps kml you can not do? I have to create the placemark with google API to make them clickable?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `placemark` variable is null when you are trying to add the event handler.

At a guess either the url or id is wrong in the line

```
var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl('http://web.uniparthenope.it/~0124000489/tw-2013/place.kml#campania');
```

or else you are calling it before the kml dom has actually loaded and so the placemark can't be found.

To fix, try calling the placemark accessor and adding the event listener from within the event callback for the fetchKml operation.

Something like so.

```
var href = 'http://web.uniparthenope.it/~0124000489/tw-2013/place.kml'
google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, fetchKmlCallback);

function fetchKmlCallback(kml) {
  if(kml) {
     ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kml);
     var placemark = ge.getElementByUrl(href + '#campania');
     google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'click', playTour);
  }
}

function playTour() { /* handle playing here */ }
```

Looking at the KML in the link you provided there doesn't seem to be a `<gx:Tour>` defined or linked to. So it is impossible to say how you should handle the playing part. It sounds like you want to load a complex tour (i.e. there will be more in the KML document than just a single `<gx:Tour>` feature) so perhaps it would be best to read through the [touring documentation for the the Api](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/touring) it clearly shows how to handle all this.

Comment: <code>function finished(object) {
    if (object) {
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(object); 
    }
   placemark = ge.getElementByUrl(url + '#campania');
   google.earth.addEventListener(placemark, 'click', playTour);
 }​</code> Thanks for the reply, I tried this way but it does not work, when I click on the placemark me the name of the placemark and does not start the tour

Comment: Your question was about making a loaded placemark clickable and an `Uncaught TypeError` - not about playing tours. So what do you mean it does not work? What did you expect it to do? To play a tour you would need to add the code to do it! see: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/touring